# MYSQL query needs improvement

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have a query below that produces a simple list of plants (the field named "thriller")

**Problem:**

Query below considers **only the first sequential set** of matching items from the table, then displays them in random order.   The query is not considering other matching items that are found later in the table.

**Solution Needed:**

I want the query to choose random results from ALL items in the table, not only the first set of matching results.

```
$row_object = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( 
    "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}personal_creations_assistant
     WHERE pot_sun_exposure = %s
     AND pot_height = %s
     AND pot_size = %s
     AND pot_shape = %s
     AND pot_placement = %s
     GROUP BY thriller 
     ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,3
   ",
    $sun_exposure,
    $height,
    $size,
    $shape,
    $placement
   ) 
 );
```

Comment: What database interface layer are you using here? I don't recognize it.

Comment: @tadman, I'm sorry - this query is in Wordpress - but the core `MYSQL` is there :)

Comment: Just wanted to know to tag it properly.

Comment: Why do you have a GROUP BY clause? You have no aggregasting functions.

Comment: @Strawberry, this seemed to work in producing the results I need, except for the total random results part of it :)

Comment: I.e. - it doesn't work! Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH A (TYPICAL) DESIRED RESULT SET

Comment: OK - I'm hearing you my friend!

Comment: If you remove `ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,3`, you really get the entire expected result set?

Comment: @Marcus Adams, I get all of the results, but any duplicates are excluded when I keep `GROUP BY`  in the query

Comment: Why do you have duplicates? What's your PRIMARY KEY?

Comment: @Strawberry, the list of plants (aka "thrillers") can have multiple results, but I was trying to narrow it down to display on one result. I thought `GROUP BY` was doing this.  I don't know what you mean by PRIMARY KEY.  Sorry.

Comment: If you don't know that, then I'm afraid we have bigger problems!

Comment: Haha...yes, I don't know how I get by, but I'm full-time. I must be genius in other ways.  Maybe I'm genius at asking smarter people than me what the hell to do :) haha.

Answer (score 0):

If i get it right, you want to get some random rows from database. Random 3 rows. 
You could do it with php. First make a `COUNT` to find how many rows you have total. Then say you call your variable $rowstotal; you make another one `$limit_s = rand(0, $rowstotal);` Then you add it to your query:

```
... LIMIT $limit_s, 3
```